# Data frame output as a single line

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and rows. I am wanting to export this as a .txt file with all values on the **same line** (i.e one row), with individual values seperated by "," and data from the rows of the df separated by ":"

```
w<- c(1,5)
x<- c(2,6)
y<- c(3,7)
z<- c(4,8)
df<-data.frame(w,x,y,z)
```

the output would look like this

```
1,2,3,4:5,6,7,8:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write it to a file, use:

```
write.table(df, "df.csv", col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, sep = ",", eol = ":")
```

If you want the output in R you can use `do.call()` and `paste()`:

```
do.call(paste, c(df, sep = ",", collapse = ":"))

[1] "1,2,3,4:5,6,7,8"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can combine data row-wise using `apply` and `paste` data together with `collapse = ":"`.

```
paste0(apply(df, 1, toString), collapse = ":")
#[1] "1, 2, 3, 4:5, 6, 7, 8"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_c`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
    reduce(str_c, sep=",") %>%
    str_c(collapse=";")
#[1] "1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8"
```